# kubectl get all - command return - Throttling request

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Running `kubectl get all` returns Throttling request errors

How can I debug and fix this issue?

```
I0223 10:28:04.717522   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 1.1688991s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/apis/apps/v1?timeout=32s
I0223 10:28:14.913541   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 5.79656704s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/apis/authorization.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
I0223 10:28:24.914386   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 7.394979677s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/apis/cert-manager.io/v1alpha2?timeout=32s
I0223 10:28:35.513643   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 1.196992376s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/api/v1?timeout=32s
I0223 10:28:45.516586   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 2.79962307s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/apis/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
I0223 10:28:55.716699   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 4.600430975s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/apis/node.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s
I0223 10:29:05.717707   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 6.196503125s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1?timeout=32s
I0223 10:29:15.914744   44883 request.go:655] Throttling request took 7.99827047s, request: GET:https://192.168.64.2:8443/apis/acme.cert-manager.io/v1alpha2?timeout=32s
```

Comment: Which version of kubectl are you using? There was an issue with kubectl 1.17 performance which was fixed with [86168](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/86168).  Where are you running this? Can you provide more details/context?

Comment: Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:51:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Answer (score 22):

To diagnose kubectl commands, you select a level of verbosity when running the command.
If you run `kubectl -v=9` you'll get a load of debug output.

If you look in there you may find the permissions for your cache directory within .kube are invalid.

```
I0511 09:28:13.431116  260204 cached_discovery.go:87] failed to write cache to /home/$USER/.kube/cache/discovery/CLUSTER_NAME/security.istio.io/v1beta1/serverresources.json due to mkdir /home/$USER/.kube/cache/discovery: permission denied
```

To resolve this I simply set the permissions to allow the cache data to be written.

```
chmod 755 -R ~/.kube/cache
```

This resolved the problem for me - hope it helps others.

Comment: in my case `chmod` wasn't enough. an additional `sudo chown myuser:mygroup -R ~/.kube` was required.

Answer (score 4):

just remove the sudo rm -rf ~/.kube/cache/

it's worked for me. don't spend too much time on this

Answer (score 2):

According to Red Hat "Due to increasing number of Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs) installed in the RHOCP - Cluster the requests reaching for API discovery were limited by the client code."

I had a lot of CRDs on my OpenShift cluster and I observed this issue. Is it the case on your Kubernetes cluster?

Updating kubectl version worked for me.

Comment: I was getting "client-side throttling, not priority and fairness" for a while with `oc` (OpenShift client), and it was resolved using the [latest oc version](https://mirror.openshift.com/pub/openshift-v4/clients/ocp/latest/openshift-client-linux.tar.gz). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is about kubernetes discovery cache.

background, upstream status...  details are here [The Kubernetes Discovery Cache: Blessing and Curse](https://jonnylangefeld.com/blog/the-kubernetes-discovery-cache-blessing-and-curse)